# MySql not considering space at right

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT bill_number 
FROM table1 
WHERE type='retailsale' 
  AND category = 'VIP '
```

please note `category = 'VIP '` has one space after VIP, but the selected result has all datas (ie VIP and VIP with space), how can I select (`category = 'VIP '`) with space only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SQL `LIKE` operator

```
SELECT bill_number 
FROM table1 
WHERE type='retailsale' 
AND category LIKE 'VIP%'
```